# jQuery menu is displayed behind my div element

Tags: jquery, menu, datatable

in my page i have two divs - one for holding jQuery menu and the other for jQuery.dataTable (extension from datatables.net).

```
<div id='divMenu'/>
<div id='divTable'/>
```

I render my data table in the second div

```
$('#divTable').append(myTable);
myTable.dataTable({...});
```

then dynamically construct jQuery menu and append to the first div

```
$('#divMenu').append(myMenu);
myMenu.menu();
```

now when i'm expanding my menu some of its submenu actions go under(behind) the second div. Can you advise anything? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `z-index` CSS property. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).